# simple method injecting javascript using cefsharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

i am trying to inject javascript after the page loaded. 
this is my code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2 {

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{

InitializeComponent();
        InitBrowser();
    }

    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.example.com");
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, IsBrowserInitializedChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.IsBrowserInitialized)
        {
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("alert('test');");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }
}
}
```

after i run, there is no alert show.
if there is someone can help me with simple example i am very grateful

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach the event to the `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance.

`browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged;`